# pthreads: What happens if I create threads with same thread IDs?

Tags: pthreads

I am creating 2 threads with same thread IDs by doing this:

```
pthread_t pt;
int rc1, rc2, t1, t2;
t1 = 0;
t2 = 1;
rc1 = pthread_create(&pt, NULL, func(), (void*)&t1);
rc2 = pthread_create(&pt, NULL, func(), (void*)&t2);
```

`func()` just prints the passed parameter

What I found out is that output can be any of `0` then `1` or `1` then `0`. What is really happening here? Is this case in anyway different from using two `pthread_t` values?

Comment: The difference to using two `pthread_t` objects is that you can't join with the first thread in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am creating 2 threads with same thread IDs by doing this:

No you aren't. That's impossible.

The `pthread_create` function creates a new thread (with a unique ID) and stores the ID of the new thread in the `pthread_t` passed as the first argument. That argument is an *out* parameter, meaning the value of the `pthread_t` that you pass in is not used, a new value is stored to it for you to use after the call finishes.

What you're doing is creating two threads with different IDs, but you are overwriting the variable that holds the first ID when the second thread is created.

That means you only *know* one of the thread IDs, but there are still two different IDs.

If you don't know the ID of the first thread (because you overwrite the variable that stored the ID) then you can't join it, or detach it, or send it a signal.

Answer (score 1):

> What I found out is that output can be any of 0 then 1 or 1 then 0. What is really happening here? Is this case in anyway different from using two pthread_t values?

It won't make any difference. Using two thread IDs won't have any effect on the order of execution.

> What happens if I create threads with same thread IDs?

If you don't have a thread ID then you can't *join* (using `pthread_join()`) with it or sending signals to it (using `pthread_signal()`), adjusting scheduling parameters (using `pthread_setschedparam` / `pthread_getschedparam`) etc. Other than that, it's fine.